# Publish the jar file first and then pom file using artifactoryPublish

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Is there a way to force artifactoryPublish task to publish the jar file first and then the pom file ? Or make pom file visible to others only when jar file is available.

We have multiple Git repositories where the jars are shared across the repositories. The Hudson build for them is triggered almost at the same time. So we have hit this case of gradle finding the pom but not the jar; But when we try to look into artifactory we see both. Just that we see jar gets uploaded couple of seconds later than the pom.

What is the best way to solve this (other than changing the time when Hudson build triggers).